# Replace lines using sed command with regex

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace some lines in a file using the sed linux command. 
Here is what I want to achieve:

```
 cn.x1.x2 y -> cn_x1.x2 y
 cn.x1.x2.x3 y  -> cn_x1_x2.x3 y
 cn.x1.x2.x3.x4 y -> cn_x1_x2_x3.x4 y
```

I want to find any word that starts with 'cn' and replace the dots with underscore until the second last word. 
How can I achieve this using a regular expression?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take this in two steps with `sed`:

```
echo 'cn.x1.x2.x3.x4 y' | sed -r 's|\.|_|g; s|\_([^_]*)$|.\1|'
```

First step replaces all of the dots with an underscore `s|\.|_|g;`

Second step replaces all but the last underscore with a dot. `s|\_([^_]*)$|.\1|`

Comment: Yes this is what I want. How can I prevent the replace only to lines starting with 'cn'?  I have tried like this    echo 'cn.x1.x2.x3.x4 y' | sed -r 's|/^cn\.|_|g; s|/^cn\_([^_]*)$|.\1|' but it doesn't work

Comment: @Bad_Pan if your real input has lines that you don't want changed you should have shown that in the sample input/output in your question. Now we're in the "what else didn't she tell us?" phase of groaning...

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/\./_/ while /cn.*\..*\./' < input > output
```

In other words, replace `.` by `_` while there are at least two dots.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, by gnu sed:

```
 sed -E 'h; s/(cn\S+)\.\S+\s\S+$/\1/;s/\./_/g;G;s/(.*)\ncn\S+(\.\S+\s\S+)$/\1\2/' d
```

by perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?!.[^.]+\s\S+$)\./_/xg' d
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/\.([^.]*\.)/_\1/;ta' file
```

Replace the first of two periods by an underscore and repeat until the match fails.